# In which thread are iOS completion handler blocks called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, objective-c-blocks

For example, in `GKScore`'s `reportScoreWithCompletionHandler` ([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKScore/reportScoreWithCompletionHandler%3a)), suppose you call

```
[score reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
   // do some stuff that may be thread-unsafe
}];
```

In which thread will the completion handler be called: the main thread, the same thread as `reportScoreWithCompletionHandler` was called, or a different thread (presumably the thread that the actual score reporting is done)?

In other words, does the work done in the completion handler need to be thread-safe (as in, it doesn't matter what thread it's done in)?

Answer (score 6):

In practical terms it doesn't matter.

If you need your completion to run in the main thread, just dispatch it to the main thread:

```
[score reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // do your stuff here
    });
}];
```

Comment: Interesting. Does this interleave perfectly with the run loop? (That is, when the completion handler is called, will the dispatched task be called right before the next run loop iteration, or could there be some delay?)

Comment: I think the main thread runloop will process queued blocks as part of the normal event processing cycle.  So it should happen "soon" but as with all things runloop related, timing isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Interesting, indeed.  I use the completion handler of UIPrintInteractionController and it always gets called on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific thread for completion handlers, apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1408085-completionblock) says it will be a secondary thread (Definitely not the main thread). You can use [DispatchQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue) to access different threads in iOS.