# Waiting on Multiple Async Tasks to Complete

Tags: ios

I like to show a loading message when the app is fetching news and videos. Currently, I have the following code:

```
 [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

        [self loadVersion];
        [self loadFeaturedNews];
        [self loadFeaturedVideo];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

        });
    });
```

I would like to dismiss the controller and hide the progress view only when all the tasks (news, videos) are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using AFNetworking, you might want to look at [`enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations`](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:progressBlock:completionBlock:).  I'd refer you to the [AFNetworking FAQ](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ):

> **How can I wait for a group of requests to finish before processing them?**
>
> Use [`enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests`] or [`enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations`] to batch a series of requests together, specifying a callback for when all of the requests have finished. As mentioned in the question about waiting for completion blocks to finish, you may not want to set completion blocks on each individual operation, and instead access the response object properties directly in the batch completion block.

---

I gather that `loadVersion`, `loadFeaturedNews`, and `loadFeaturedVideo` methods are each asynchronously downloading content. If you were using `NSURLConnection`, I would suggest  changing them to operate synchronously. The specifics of the solution will vary depending upon how you're currently downloading stuff in those routines e.g. if you're using `NSURLConnection` method, `initWithRequest`, you could use [`sendSynchronousRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJHAHGI).

Personally, I'd be inclined to combine that with doing the requests concurrently with dispatch groups or `NSOperationQueue` dependencies, but first focus on getting them to run synchronously. I'd actually use `NSOperationQueue` so I could easily cap the number of concurrent operations to four, or something reasonable like that.

By the way, I'm not suggesting you change the code in your question at all. Keep that `dispatch_async`. I'm suggesting you fix the `loadVersion`, `loadFeaturedNews`, and `loadFeaturedVideo` methods, themselves, to operate synchronously.

Comment: I am using AFNetworking but I can try making the calls syncrously!

Comment: @azamsharp In which case I might retract my comment and suggest that you look at `AFNetworking` [FAQ](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ) which has a section titled "How can I wait for a group of requests to finish before processing them?"

Answer (score 0):

Then use completion handler for this. in that you can write your code which is to be executed after completion

```
completion:^ (BOOL finished) {

    }
```

Comment: If there are 10 tasks and I want to make sure that all 10 are completed then will it involve 10 completion handlers.

Comment: you can include those 10 task in one single handler

Comment: There is no completion handler for dispatch_async

Comment: @azamsharp:check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267411/in-which-thread-are-ios-completion-handler-blocks-called

Comment: @azamsharp: also check this one http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_sync

Comment: I checked the links but I don't think they refer to my problem. In my code the loadVersion and loadFeaturedNews is fired but the inner dispatch is fired instantly after calling those methods.